# Have R source() preserve empty lines

Tags: r

I would like 'source()' to reproduce the input file.  This almost gets there:

```
source(in.file, echo=TRUE, max.deparse=100000, prompt.echo="", print.eval=FALSE)
```

Unfortunately it discards empty lines!  I don't see this behaviour mentioned in the documentation.  Is it a bug?

To preserve the readability of the source, and avoid spurious version control changes, I'd like to reproduce it *exactly*.  How can I achieve it?

I could use a hack:  first replace all empty lines with "#empty", then run 'source()' in R, then reverse the substitution in the output.  But that's circuitous and ugly.

**Example input**.  In real use I'd define 'foo' in my R session, before calling 'source', but to keep this self-contained, I'm including it here:

```
foo <- function(x) {
   if (x > 100) cat ("# Wow!\n")
}
# comment kept.
# empty lines?

foo(2)
foo(4)
foo(16)
foo(256)


foo(2015)
foo(9)
foo(22)
# the end
```

**Desired output** -- I'd like to annotate any large 'x' with "Wow":

```
foo <- function(x) {
   if (x > 100) cat ("# Wow!\n")
}
# comment kept.
# empty lines?

foo(2)
foo(4)
foo(16)
foo(256)
# Wow!


foo(2015)
# Wow!
foo(9)
foo(22)
# the end
```

**Actual output**:

```
foo <- function(x) {
   if (x > 100) cat ("# Wow!\n")
}

# comment kept.
# empty lines?

foo(2)

foo(4)

foo(16)

foo(256)
# Wow!

foo(2015)
# Wow!

foo(9)

foo(22)

# the end
```

I get an empty line after every statement or comment block.  Empty lines in the input are lost.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You want to run the script, but the only output is the text of the script itself, identical to the input? What about printed output? Errors?

Comment: What about `readLines`? Or `knitr`? Can you give a little context?

Comment: `source` doesn't remove empty lines from the input file in its echo on my system with these settings and default options otherwise.

Comment: @Spacedman yes, if something prints output I want it.  Hopefully I don't have errors :-)  But if I do, I'd want to see them.

Comment: @Gregor nope, I'd like to run 'source' to parse and evaluate my code, not 'readLines' or 'knitr'.  Context: I'd like to annotate the source.

Comment: Can you show a small example illustrating what you're trying to do? The more you say, the more `knitr` sounds perfect: it parses and evaluates code, captures and prints output, and makes for very easy annotation. If there's a reason `knitr` won't work for you, an example including input and desired output might make things clearer.

Comment: In particular you may want to look at the knitr functions `stitch` and `spin`, which are designed to work with a raw R script as input without the need for further markup.

Comment: I edited the question to include an example, because Markdown (and length) are limited in comments.

Comment: To restate:  'source(echo=true)' seems to discard empty lines.  The community feels I was wrong calling 'source' at all, and should use some function from package 'knitr' instead.  

Yet the 3 original questions remain:  Is this behavior known?  Did I miss it in the documentation or is it a bug?  Is there a way to change it?

Comment: Apparently `knitr` writes files with the same base name but different extensions in the current directory.  I had tried `knit`; it simply copies the source to .txt, without running it.

Comment: @Thomas: thanks for the pointers, I tried those.  `stitch` generates .tex and .pdf; neither is suitable as R source code; it discards empty lines (just like `source`) in the PDF, additionally coalesces comments, and prefixes output with "## ".  `spin` writes .md and .html; with some post-processing on the triple backticks, the .md could be transformed back to legal R code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you're saying here, but I think you misunderstand what `source()` is actually doing. First, it reads in a file using `readLines()`, then in parses it into series of R expressions, then it prints out the parsed, evaluated expressions (possibly with the original parsed expressions at a prompt, and possibly other information if `verbose = TRUE`). To understand this, let's take this in steps and see what's happening:

### Step 1. Read in file:

```
> readLines(in.file)
 [1] "foo <- function(x) {"                "   if (x > 100) cat (\"# Wow!\\n\")"
 [3] "}"                                   "# comment kept."                    
 [5] "# empty lines?"                      ""                                   
 [7] "foo(2)"                              "foo(4)"                             
 [9] "foo(16)"                             "foo(256)"                           
[11] ""                                    ""                                   
[13] "foo(2015)"                           "foo(9)"                             
[15] "foo(22)"                             "# the end"                          
[17] ""                                    ""
```

### Step 2. Parse expressions:

```
> parse(in.file)
expression(foo <- function(x) {
   if (x > 100) cat ("# Wow!\n")
}, foo(2), foo(4), foo(16), foo(256), foo(2015), foo(9), foo(22))
```

### Step 3. Evaluate and print:

Now, this is where the problem is for you. Because `source()` has created an R parse tree from the read-in file, the original structure of the file is basically completely lost. (It's a little more complicated then this actually, but you can look at the source code for yourself to see that.) To achieve your desired output, you need to change the way that R parses, evaluates, and prints each expression.

That is a lot of work, but you can make one simple change related to Step 3 that you might be happy with. Near the bottom of `source()`, you'll find the following:

```
        if (nd) {
            do.trunc <- nd > max.deparse.length
            dep <- substr(dep, 1L, if (do.trunc) 
              max.deparse.length
            else nd)
            cat("\n", dep, if (do.trunc) 
              paste(if (length(grep(sd, dep)) && length(grep(oddsd, 
                dep))) 
                " ...\" ..."
              else " ....", "[TRUNCATED] "), "\n", sep = "")
        }
```

If you remove the `"\n"` from `cat("\n", ...` as follows:

```
        if (nd) {
            do.trunc <- nd > max.deparse.length
            dep <- substr(dep, 1L, if (do.trunc) 
              max.deparse.length
            else nd)
            cat(dep, if (do.trunc) 
              paste(if (length(grep(sd, dep)) && length(grep(oddsd, 
                dep))) 
                " ...\" ..."
              else " ....", "[TRUNCATED] "), "\n", sep = "")
        }
```

You'll get something closer to your intended result:

```
> source(in.file, echo=TRUE, max.deparse=100000, prompt.echo="", print.eval=FALSE)
foo <- function(x) {
+    if (x > 100) cat ("# Wow!\n")
+ }
# comment kept.
# empty lines?

foo(2)
foo(4)
foo(16)
foo(256)
# Wow!
foo(2015)
# Wow!
foo(9)
foo(22)
# the end
```

But if you actually want to preserve whitespace exactly as in the original input file, you're going to have to change Step 2 (i.e., change the way R parses and evaluates the input file so that, basically, it evaluates an empty line to be `cat("\n")`. That's probably a lot of work to achieve.

Comment: Awesome, @Thomas, these are the crucial details!  Actually that jibes with my understanding of `source()`.  And you point me to the point where it essentially does `cat("\n", dep, "\n", sep="")` as I'm not truncating, adding newlines before **and** after.  While looking there I noticed where `source` deliberately discards leading blank lines.  I'll answer to side-step mini-Markdown.

Answer (score 0):

@Thomas points me to the relevant section of the source of `source()`, where it deliberately discards leading blank lines,

```
while (length(dep) && length(grep("^[[:blank:]]*$", 
  dep[1L]))) {
  dep <- dep[-1L]
  leading <- leading - 1L
}
```

(before printing what's left with a spurious newline).

Apparently the behavior is intentional, not considered worth mention in the documentation, yet "known" to the more seasoned R users.